# How to change Highcharts xAxis formatting from yearly to monthly?

Tags: javascript, html, json, highcharts

I have the following JSON Highcharts data:

```
"xAxis": {
      "type": "datetime",
      "dateTimeLabelFormats": {
        "month": "%b %y"
      },
      "labels": {
        "style": {
          "color": "#000000",
          "fontWeight": "normal",
          "font-size": "100%",
          "font-family": "sans-serif"
        }
      }
    },
```

I want to split the xAxis into months but I am still getting the xAxis in years (2010, 2012, 2012 ...).

How do I change it to something like Jan 10, Feb 10, Mar 10... ?

Comment: If you do just `"month": "%b"`, what happens?

Comment: @CalvinGodfrey it's still showing in years. Basically, even if I remove the dateTimeLabelFormats option, it still is in years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How highcharts appears to work is that it determines which time range to use (milliseconds, seconds, etc., all the way to years), and then checks THAT specific option for formatting.

So presumably your data is spread out far enough that it defaults to years, so to change the formatting it uses, you want to do `"year": "%b %y"`.

Comment: Doing so adds "Jan" month to the year. eg: previously it was 2010, 2011, 2012.. Now it is Jan 2010, Jan 2011, Jan 2012 etc

Comment: Are you sure you're doing lower-case y? `%Y` makes it 2010, 2011, etc., but `%y` should be 10, 11, etc.

Comment: Yeah my bad, but the issue still exists. Its showing Jan 10, Jan 11, Jan 12, but I want Jan 10, Feb 10, Mar 10..

Comment: So you want to include *every* month along the x-axis? Even if it makes the axis clustered?

Comment: Yes, that's what I need

Comment: You can add `tickInterval: 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 31` to get tick intervals of a month, but even then it might be too clustered that it only shows every other, or every third month.

Comment: This sounds like it might be a case of the [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why is it important to get a tick every month?

Comment: Yes you are right, since there are too many intervals, it is not showing anything on the xAxis. I am not sure if it is supposed to show something but because I set the tickInterval, I guess that's why the xAxis has nothing too display, so I will probably stick with yearly intervals. Thanks for the clarification, just out of curiosity, is there a workaround to generate monthly intervals, even if they are clustered?

Comment: I tried tinkering around with `minTickInterval`, but it seems to not like datetime tick marks. You can poke around on [this website](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis) to see if there are any other attributes you could use.

Comment: Just to update, I found a workaround by tinkering with tickPixelInterval and minTickInterval. Thanks. I'll mark your answer accepted as it cleared out my confusion about months.